# How prove this $1+q\int_{0}^{1}x^{1-qx}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{q}{k+1}\right)^k$

Tags: integration

show that:

> $$1+q\int_{0}^{1}x^{1-qx}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{q}{k+1}\right)^k\cdots\cdots(1)$$

I kown prove following this

> $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-qx}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{q^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$

note that
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-qx}=\int_{0}^{1}e^{qx\ln{\frac{1}{x}}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln^n{\frac{1}{x}}dx$$

let $$\ln{\dfrac{1}{x}}=t\Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln^n{\dfrac{1}{x}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(n+1)t}t^ndt=\dfrac{\Gamma{(n+1)}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$
so

> $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-qx}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{q^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$

**But** this $(1)$  I can't prove it,Thank you everyone.

Comment: Hint: the Maple command $$series(x^{-q*x+1}, x, 6) $$ produces $$ x-q\ln  \left( x \right) {x}^{2}+1/2\,{q}^{2} \left( \ln  \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2}{x}^{3}-1/6\,{q}^{3} \left( \ln  \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{3}{x}^{4}+1/24\,{q}^{4} \left( \ln  \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{4}{x}^{5}+O \left( {x}^{6} \right) 
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof goes along the same lines
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^{1-qx}dx
&=\int_0^1 xe^{-qx}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(qx\ln x^{-1})^n}{n!}dx\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^n}{n!}\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln^n x^{-1}dx\qquad\{\ln x^{-1}=t\}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^n}{n!}\int_{+\infty}^0 e^{-(n+1)t}t^n (-e^{-t})dt\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty e^{-(n+2)t}t^n dt\qquad \{(n+2)t=s\}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty e^{-s}(n+2)^{-n}s^n (n+2)^{-1}ds\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^n}{(n+2)^{n+1}}
\end{align}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
1+q\int_0^1 x^{1-qx}dx
&=1+q\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^n}{(n+2)^{n+1}}\\
&=1+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^{n+1}}{(n+2)^{n+1}}\qquad\{k=n+1\}\\
&=\frac{q^0}{(0+1)^0}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{q^k}{(k+1)^k}\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{q}{k+1}\right)^k\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Aw man. I just started typing up my answer (which I had just finished before class an hour ago but didn't have time to type up). Good job though!

Comment: My apologies,for being the first. Such things often happened to me, but not this time :-)